# Clickhouse. ReplacingMergeTree doesn't guarantee absence of duplicates

Tags: clickhouse

According to the [documentation](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree/) the ReplacingMergeTree engine does not guarantee absence of duplicates. Does it mean I must not count on this engine and I have to use my own method for control duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does mean that you must not count on this engine.

For a small  ReplacingMergeTree tables you can FINAL keyword.

```
select ... from SomeReplacingMergeTreeTable FINAL
```

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/from/#select-from-final

Or `argMax group by` or `order by ... limit by ...`

But the best solution is to redesign dataflow and avoid duplicates.

Comment: What about primary keys? In my universe it's impossible to have several records with the same primary key.

Comment: There is no primary key constrains in CH.

Comment: @CaptainVoronin unfortunatelly,  support unique primary keys on big data is really expensive